# Is there any etiquette to be observed when editing a question or an answer?

Tags: support, editing, etiquette, best-practices

I am asking this because there were a few occasions when I felt an urgent need to edit a person's solution that had been written rather poorly (e.g. using non-standard abbreviations or committing really gross spelling errors). In the end, after making the necessary edit, I received a rather rude response from the person.

I would like to know, is it an unspoken rule that one communicates privately with the person about what corrections should be made before effecting any edits?

Comment: If you received a rude response as a comment on the answer then you might flag that comment for moderator attention.

Comment: I think you edit too many unnecessary things. For example in [this edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/271481/revisions) there are at most two or three changes that lead to *visible* improvement. Nevertheless you touched *every single* formula by introducing lots of braces and spaces. Please try to change only what is *necessary*. Everybody has their own way of TeXing and parsing other people's code is an unpleasant thing to do.

Comment: Ooof. This comment by Martin has me a little self conscious where is the post that discusses unnecessary edits? I am assuming that these are costly to the community in terms of just consuming other users' time in a way that is not appreciated. Is there anything else to this?

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/minimum-suggested-edit-length

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless you are a moderator, there isn't really a method to communicate privately with another user. If a comment and reply were expected before every edit, the comments would become littered with messages about editing. However, if an edit might affect the meaning or tone of a post, a comment asking about the change would be a courtesy.

Answer (score 7):

Always note: **There is nothing wrong with editing a poor-quality post; this is a community driven website.**

Make sure that the edit is very meaningful and respects the original author. Do not make unnecessary additions to the post unless a community wiki. Sometimes, people do think that it is disrespectful to their post when you edit it, but it's *not*! An edit makes a post much more valuable. There is no etiquette as such. In addition, you can always write a proper reason to what you edited and why you did so. It'd be enough in my (and most on this site's) opinion.

Comment: Please, either add hyphen between words “community” and “driven” or change grammar away of passive voice.