# Should there be a different character limits on edits for Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, character-limit

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2703517/133152) question in Mathematics Stack Exchange where the OP neglected to specify the type of norms he wants people to help finding. The specification can be made clear by simply adding `1-` in front of the word `norms`. But that edit is not allowed at the moment due to the minimum character length limit on edits.

I am not sure if the limit is reputation related. In any case, I don't think it should apply to Mathematics Stack Exchange where complex concepts are commonly conveyed with brevity using commonly understood notations and formulas.

What do you think? If you are a Mathematics Stack Exchange user, do you think the minimum character limit on edits should be removed?

Comment: It probably opens up a can of worms. if you really have to make a single letter edit with nothing else to fix use `<!-- this is more then 6 chars -->1-` but that might get rejected if it needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: Isn't that more of an example of an edit that the OP ought to make, since as you note the "OP neglected to specify" which norm is desired?

Comment: It's ambiguous but he used 1-norm later.

Comment: @rene: Thanks for the tip. Upon some experimenting, I think making a first edit with that phrase and a second edit removing it will traverse the 6 character requirement.

Comment: @Argyll but that bumps the post twice and given your privileges your edit needs 6 reviewers (3 for the 6 chars trick and then 3 for the rollback). It is doable but I'm not sure you make many friends if you (and many others) apply this trick often. There are plenty of chatrooms for the Math site. I'm sure you can find someone with full edit privileges there and they are happy to make that edit for you so you can move on to the posts that need more work.

Comment: @rene: I see. Thank you for explaining. It was more of a coincidence that I spotted another typo and needed to amend the edit. If it's not a rollback, will it still require 6 reviewers? I often end up amending an edit (without using the 6 char trick). Will that require 3 reviewer per amendment?

Comment: @Argyll you can make edits while your suggestion is under review. That so called grace period is explained on the uber meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202288/158100) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299892). That means your additional edits only needs 3 reviewers. ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you might not be aware of this but Mathematics Stack Exchange has its [own meta site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/), which is probably a better fit for your question. Except that it has already been asked before: 
[Minimum suggested edit length](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/228959) and has a lot of support from community. However, the answer by Jeff Atwood explains the reasoning behind this, why it's not likely to be changed and that it only applies to suggested edits; once you have 2,000 reputation (like you have on Stack Overflow) you're no longer limited by the limit (pun intended).

You can always look for more things which can be improved in the post; for example, I see an "its" which should be "it's". Since the post is quite new, you can also leave a comment asking the author (or somebody with enough reputation) to make the edit for you. If there's *really nothing else* which can be improved in the post you can use [@rene's workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308252/should-there-be-a-different-character-limits-on-edits-for-math-stackexchange/308254#comment1004278_3082520), it's an HTML comment which won't be shown in the display version of the post but it does count for the 6 character limit.