# Can someone with rep fix this?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, character-limit

I was able to make a [useful change to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913824/difference-between-dot-product-and-cross-product), but then when I saw a need to correct a sign, I could not do it because it wasn't enough characters.

Now I have a wholesale change **back** in the review queue, which I don't want.

Comment: This isn't actually about a review-audit, is it.

Comment: no, and i didn't intend to include it.  but it **is** about what i think is a frustrating bug.

Comment: Related: [Minimum suggested edit length](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2216)).

Comment: You are a new contributor to MSE Meta which is what that message means.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson There are some feature request on mother meta ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314509/update-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-meta-to-say-new-contributor-to-meta)) about the new-contributor problem..

Comment: no, @PeterPhipps, i am decidedly **NOT** a new contributor.  i have been around for at least 2 years.  but recently i spent a bunch of my rep on some bonuses for questions.

Comment: I think there are good reasons for requiring a minimum of six characters for those who can edit only to *suggest* an edit, which is then reviewed.  I review my share of "suggested edits", and the biggest problem I see is minor edits, such as, instead of one dollar sign on each end of an equation, the editor puts another one on each end.  It is good that doing so on one or two equations, with no other edits, should be blocked.  Such an edit is seen as a "trivial" edit that does not essentially improve the question.  Since successful suggested edits earn 2 rep points per successful edit,

Comment: but, @amWhy, we cannot even **suggest** an edit.  if what i want to do is simply correct a wrong number or a wrong symbol, i cannot do it (or even suggest it for review) unless i pad this correction with some chaff somewhere.

Comment: ...it should not be surprising that some users under 2k rep suggest *lots of edits*, and unfortunately, sometimes they are very very trivial, unnecessary edits.  So, those suggesting an edit worth 2 rep points to them, I say: "earn it!"

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  Such an edit may very well be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever, or as "clearly conflicts with the author's intention"...

Comment: but the problem is, **particularly** with math and disciplines that express their content with math (like *electrical engineering*, which is mine) is that a small error can make an expression simple *wrong* and a small correction can turn it from *wrong* to *correct*.  in this case, it was the use of the matrix vs. determinant notation (i had to turn `bmatrix` into `vmatrix`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has now been fixed by the author of the post.

In the future, note that you could have made some (admittedly minor) grammar and formatting corrections; see [my revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2913824/revisions). This would've put you over the 6 character limit.

Another option would've been to leave a comment informing the author of the mistake, so that they can correct it themselves.

Comment: but i didn't see the other corrections to make.  the basic problem is that i cannot make incremental corrections.

Comment: oh, and i am not the person who downvoted this answer.

Comment: I especially like the suggestion to leave a Comment for the author.   Many new users benefit from a bit of encouragement to edit their posts, "getting their feet wet."